# rewrite some urls since menu change

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having trouble getting

site.com/member-videos

into

site.com/videos

or in reality

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^/community/member-videos/
#RewriteRule (.*) http://site.com/community/videos/$1 [R=301,L]
```

this seems to loop !

for me the above says find the match for '/community/member-videos/' and send anything like that to the url after...I have lost too much time now on this typical I would guess issue and looked at a lot of similar online but nothing quite works for this case..
thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://site.com/community/videos/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is wrong, it will get you into an infinite loop.

Try this one:

```
RewriteRule http://site.com/community/member-videos/$1 ^community/videos/(.*)$ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: it didn't seem to see it - no reaction - here is the real url in fact

http://caribbean-diving.com/community/caribbean-videos/ to 
http://caribbean-diving.com/community/videos/

Comment: protocol and hostname are never part of the string matched against in a `RewriteRule`

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it. The variable your condition matches against *is a host, and **not** a URI*. If you need to check the host, it must only be the hostname (not URI path at all), e.g. `site.com`. You need to use a `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable for what you are matching against:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/videos/
RewriteRule ^/?member-videos(.*)$ /videos$1 [L,R=301]
```

The example you gave doesn't have the `community` part in the URI at all, if it's not in the URL, it won't appear in the string sent to the rewrite engine. But your rules has `/community` in them, so if in fact you need that path, then:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/community/videos/
RewriteRule ^/?community/member-videos(.*)$ /community/videos$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?caribbean-diving\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/community/videos/
RewriteRule ^/?community/member-videos(.*)$ /community/videos$1 [L,R=301]

hmmm - still seems to give me the 500 error..but thanks I am learning more about these complicated beasts.

Comment: there was some typos in there - I'm sure you were right in principle Jon. And I got it working with just the rule part no condition lines needed..

RewriteRule ^/?community/caribbean-videos(.*)$ /community/videos$1 [L,R=301]